# How is memory and storage shared between tasks running stateful applications?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've been reasearching docker swarms and found out that a swarm is a collection of nodes, nodes are computers that run services, services are schedulers of tasks, and tasks are running containers. Services are made out of a single container image and can be made out of multiple redundant tasks.

My question is: if tasks are redundant, how is memory and storage shared between them, assuming your service is running a stateful application like a database (storage) of a website backend (memory)?

- Are the resource requirements multiplied and sinchronized regularly or in real-time? By that logic shouldn't there be a "master task"?
- If not, then stateful applications should have at maximum 1 task replica per service, and each redundancy unit should be a new actively mantained service (like databases, for instance)?

Although my application is very little, I'm trying to implement it using the best practices in order to learn as much as possible.

Comment: It's very unusual for memory to be shared between components in a cluster except in specialty high-performance-computing scenarios. Shared disk, when it needs to happen, is typically done with volumes. That said -- this is too broad a question to be a good fit for Stack Overflow's format; there are lots of different architectural choices, and "best practice" is often open to opinion.

Comment: Database clustering works in Docker the same way it works anywhere else -- if you have one of the few databases designed for shared storage (like Oracle RAC) you set up shared storage and have common volume mounts available; with more conventional databases each instance has its own storage and they communicate with each other over the network (or, sometimes, by using a shared storage location as a drop point for content updates, as with PostgreSQL's transaction log shipping); but it's all very specific to the design of the particular database service; there's no one "best practice" approach.

Comment: See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) for a description of how the philosophy on differs across sites in the network. We require narrow, specific questions and frown on "best practice" discussions here; high-level design practice questions are much more likely to be accepted at [programmers.se], but do read their rules before posting there.

Comment: (Another note on content: Not all services really make sense being viewed as "tasks" -- that's a very specific model that doesn't apply everywhere; there are specialty scheduling tools that are focused narrowly on distributed locking and queue management that make sense when that's the kind of application you're building, but not all the world works that way).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wrote more details about my train of thought and posted on the devops stack exchange.